# Saving a Bool when user exits app

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am at the last stage of my game. I want to save a boolean value `notYetRated` to `NSUserDefaults`.

The bool is used to see if the user has rated the app (just clicked a button that takes him to rate the app).

This is the way I set it up:

```
var notYetRated = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
func rateButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!)
{

    self.runAction(buttonSound, withKey: "buttonSound")
    var url  = NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/app/id968231672")

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
        if !notYetRated.boolForKey("notYetRated") {
            notYetRated.setBool(true, forKey: "notYetRated")
            scrollView.removeFromSuperview()
            SetUpScrollView()
        }

    }

}
```

For some reason every time I kill the app it doesn't work. The value remains false.

Anyone have any suggestions or see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might find the [iRate](https://cocoapods.org/pods/iRate) pod useful.

Comment: For goodness sake, don't call an instance of NSUserDefaults "notYetRated"!!!! That's a truly dreadful, confusing name for a general purpose shared system object like NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Worse yet, you've defined your NSUserDefaults object outside of your function, so it has global scope and will persist for the life of your program (or more accurately for the life of the module in which it's contained.) Move that variable inside the rateButtonPressed function and call it something like `defaults`.

Comment: @DuncanC but I need to use that in other parts of the app...

Comment: Where do you call this method?

Answer (score 0):

just add synchronize to commit your changes to the backend of NSUserDefaults .

your code should become:

```
var notYetRated = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
func rateButtonPressed(sender:UIButton!)
{

    self.runAction(buttonSound, withKey: "buttonSound")
    var url  = NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=app_id&mt=8")        
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
        if !notYetRated.boolForKey("notYetRated") {
            notYetRated.setBool(true, forKey: "notYetRated")
            notYetRated.synchronize()
            scrollView.removeFromSuperview()
            SetUpScrollView()
        }

    }

}
```

[documentations](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize)

And it seems like you have a problem with the URL itself, it can be fixed by using an appropriate URL such as:

```
  var url  = NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=968231672&mt=8")
```

[List of supported schemes on iOS](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus actually since the application is leaving the foreground there is a very good chance apple might kill it before the next automatic synch, which means synchronize should be used to ensure consistency

Comment: @Jeremy now everything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
if let ratingURL = NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/app/id968231672") {
    println("good url")
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(ratingURL) {
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(ratingURL) {
            if !NSUserDefaults().boolForKey("notYetRated") {
                NSUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "notYetRated")
                println(NSUserDefaults().boolForKey("notYetRated"))
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    println("bad url")
}
```